# I'm building a project with a vue-cli that takes a lot of time to build every time it refreshes, so there's a way to prevent this

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, webpack

I used the vue-cli2.9+ version of the project, and every time the project started or after I changed the code, it took a long time for building moudles to run my project again. I wanted to reduce the time for each building

Comment: Do you have `mode: "development"` in your webpack config?

Comment: No, there is only one vue. Config. Js in this project. There is no 'development' in it.

Comment: const path = require('path')

const resolve = dir => {
  return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}
const BASE_URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'live'
  ? '/'
  : '/'

module.exports = {
  publicPath: BASE_URL,
  lintOnSave: true,
  assetsDir: 'static',
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.symlinks(true)
    config.resolve.alias
      .set('@', resolve('src'))
      .set('_c', resolve('src/components'))
      .set('$plugin', resolve('src/plugin'))
  },
  productionSourceMap: false
}

Answer (score 0):

Webpack has that feature called Hot module. You should implement this into your development webpack because it helps alot when you have big project 
https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement

Comment: Yes, I have added the hot update, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. It will compile automatically after every change, and there will be a long wait after the 70% chunk graph appears. I think it is not the problem of hot update, I think I may need a tool to analyze the reason why it is so slow